# How to pass list of pairs to a function from a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I have a list of pairs:

```
List_Pairs = [
    ["Eat at Joe's", "Eat my shorts"],
    ["Eat well", "Eat mama's pies"],
     ...]
```

I have a function that computes the similarity between a pair of sentences and returns whether that is more than a threshold ratio:

```
def Jaccard_Sim(pair):
    """return Jaccard Similarity Index for similarity between two sentences"""
    ratio = len(set(pair[0][1]).intersection(pair[1])/ 
    float(len(set(pair[0]).union(pair[0][1]))))
    return (ratio > 0.66)
```

I call it for each of my pairs:

```
sim_list = (Jaccard_Sim(pair) for pair in combo_pairs)
```

... and try to print it:

```
print(list(sim_list))
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-b9508b63e83f> in <module>()
----> 1 list(sim_list)

<ipython-input-49-8ee7726dd300> in <genexpr>(.0)
----> 1 sim_list = (Jaccard_Sim(pair) for pair in combo_pairs)

<ipython-input-47-f211879c6e96> in Jaccard_Sim(pair)
     12 def Jaccard_Sim(pair):
     13     """return Jaccard Similarity Index for similarity between two sentences"""
---> 14     ratio = len(set(pair[0] 
[1]).intersection(pair[1])/float(len(set(pair[0]).union(pair[0][1]))))
     15     return (ratio > 0.66)
     16 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list
```

Comment: Please also supply a `pair` sample as described in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `pair[0]` is probably a list. You can't do e.g. `set([[1,2]])` because lists are not mutable and thus, not hashable

Comment: @CristiFati please list example, it is a list of pairs. Or else, please clarify.

Comment: You should build this logic from the bottom up: make sure that you compute the Jacquard similarity correctly before you put it into a function.  At the moment, you're trying to perform intersection / union between a set of one character and a string.

Comment: Also note that your list of pairs is not legal syntax.

Comment: I didn't see the pairs sample at the beginning. Add a `print(pair)` as the 1st line in the function. Also I see `pair[0][1]` and `pair[0]` which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

Set elements *must* be hashable items.  A list is mutable, which means that it's not hashable.  If you can simply switch to tuples, that should solve your hashing problem.

Your computation problem is a killer.  Look at your expression:

```
ratio = (len(set(pair[0][1]).intersection(pair[1])) /
         float(len(set(pair[0]).union(pair[0][1]))))
```

`pair[0][1]` is a single character.  `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` are strings.  Since the length of a character is 1, this expression quickly reduces to:

```
1.0 / len(pair[0])
```

This is not quite Jaccard's formula.  Try this:

```
combo_pairs = [ ['Eat at Joes', 'Eat my shorts'], ['Eat well', 'Eat mamas pies'] ]

def Jaccard_Sim(pair):
    """return Jaccard Similarity Index for similarity between two sentences"""
    chars0 = set(pair[0])
    chars1 = set(pair[1])
    ratio = float(len(chars0.intersection(chars1))) / \
                  len(chars0.union(chars1)) 
    print(chars0, chars1, ratio)
    return (ratio > 0.66)

sim_list = (Jaccard_Sim(pair) for pair in combo_pairs)

print(list(sim_list))
```

Output:

```
{'s', 'E', 'o', 'e', 'J', ' ', 't', 'a'} {'s', 'E', 'y', 'r', 'o', ' ', 'h', 't', 'm', 'a'} 0.5
{'E', 'e', ' ', 'l', 't', 'a', 'w'} {'s', 'E', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'i', 't', 'm', 'a'} 0.45454545454545453
[False, False]
```